# Gradually fade top of elements only on scroll without fixed background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if this is even possible, but what I'm trying to do is fade content out as it reaches the header.

I've seen solutions such as this:

```
    // fade content out at top of div before it reaches LD icon and nav
    $('.content-block *').each(function (index, item) {
        $(item).children().each(function (indexChild, child) {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop() - $(child).offset().top + 115;
            console.log('st: '+st);
            $(child).css({ 'opacity': (1 - st / 1.1) }); // changing the / 1.1 supposedly changes the intensity of the effect
        });

    });
```

But this causes content blocks to fade out prematurely on mobile. For instance, the top of the content block will reach the top of the screen, so it fades out, yet the bottom is not visible yet, so they never get a chance to read all the content.

I'm trying to fade out gradually, as if we had a gradient PNG image overlay. However, I'm trying to find a solution that does not require a fixed background, as I'm trying to do this over a live video background.

Comment: can you add some code ? your `html` for example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z6r863ep/